# Pandas DataFrame use Timedelta to set time in H:M:S:f format to 00:00:00:000

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timedelta, string-to-datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following column `(first column = index)`:

```
0         14:43:45:921

1         14:43:45:923

2         14:43:45:925
```

I would like to modify this column, or add another column with the time starting at `0`:

```
0         00:00:00.000

1         00:00:00.002

2         00:00:00.004
```

So far, I've tried the following code:

```
df['time'].apply(pd.Timedelta)
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
expected hh:mm:ss format
```

To me, the problem is

a) convert the time format `HH:MM:SS:fff` to `HH:MM:SS.fff` and

b) get the `timedelta` function to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Or [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].str.replace('(:)(\d+)$', r'.\2'))
```

And then subtract first value:

```
df['new'] = s.sub(s.iat[0])
print (df)
           time                    new
0  14:43:45:921        0 days 00:00:00
1  14:43:45:923 0 days 00:00:00.002000
2  14:43:45:925 0 days 00:00:00.004000
```

If need times:

```
df['new'] = s.sub(s.iat[0])
df['new1'] = df['new'].apply(lambda x: (pd.datetime.min + x).time())

print (df)
           time                    new             new1
0  14:43:45:921        0 days 00:00:00         00:00:00
1  14:43:45:923 0 days 00:00:00.002000  00:00:00.002000
2  14:43:45:925 0 days 00:00:00.004000  00:00:00.004000


print (type(df.at[0, 'new']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'>

print (type(df.at[0, 'new1']))
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution! However, I'd also like to get rid of the date, so that I end up with the time starting at 00:00:00.

Comment: @M195 - Not easy, but possible. Added to answer.